# Parsing escaped strings with boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I´m working with Spirit 2.4 and I'd want to parse a structure like this:

Text{text_field};

The point is that in text_field is a escaped string with the symbols '{', '}' and '\'.
I would like to create a parser for this using qi. I've been trying this:

```
using boost::spirit::standard::char_;
using boost::spirit::standard::string;
using qi::lexeme;
using qi::lit;

qi::rule< IteratorT, std::string(), ascii::space_type > text;
qi::rule< IteratorT, std::string(), ascii::space_type > content;
qi::rule< IteratorT, std::string(), ascii::space_type > escChar;


text %= 
  lit( "Text" ) >> '{' >>
    content >>
  "};"
  ;

content %= lexeme[ +( +(char_ - ( lit( '\\' ) | '}' ) )  >> escChar ) ];

escChar %= string( "\\\\" ) 
  | string( "\\{" ) 
  | string( "\\}" );
```

But doesn't even compile. Any idea?

Comment: The compiler error (and the line it's on) would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your grammar could be written as:

```
qi::rule< IteratorT, std::string(), ascii::space_type > text; 
qi::rule< IteratorT, std::string() > content;   
qi::rule< IteratorT, char() > escChar;   

text = "Text{" >> content >> "};";  
content = +(~char_('}') | escChar); 
escChar = '\\' >> char_("\\{}");
```

i.e.

- *text* is `Text{` followed by content followed by `}`
- *content* is at least one instance of 
      either a character (but no `}`) or 
      an escChar
- *escChar* is a single escaped `\\`, `{`, or `}`

Note, the *escChar* rule now returns a single character and discards the escaping `\\`. I'm not sure if that's what you need. Additionally, I removed the skipper for the *content* and *escChar* rules, which allows to leave off the `lexeme[]` (a rule without skipper acts like an implicit lexeme).

Comment: Hi, hkaiser and thanks for helping. I've tried your solution but it fails to parse this: Text{ \} };   I thought that it was because the parser ~char_('}') matches the backslash, but I tried the following with no succes: content = +( ~char_( "\\\\}" ) | escChar );. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, right. ~char_('}') does indeed match the backslash. I'm sorry for this oversight. If you change that to ~char_("\\}") it should not do that anymore.