# Boost spirit get the whole match as a string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to define my own grammar using boost spirit framework and I'm defining such a matching rule:

```
value = (
        char_('"') >>
        (*qi::lexeme[
                char_('\\') >> char_('\\') |
                char_('\\') >> char_('"')  |
                graph - char_('"') |
                char_(' ')
        ])[some_func] >>
        char_('"')
);
```

I'd like to assing an action - some_func - to the part of it, and pass the whole matching string as a parameter. But unfortunately I will get something like `vector<boost::variant<boost::fusion::vector2 ..a lot of stuff...)...>` . Can I somehow get the whole data as a char*, std::string or even void* with size?

Comment: what is wrong with vector?

Comment: I describe it as a vector<foo<bar<another<boost<stuff>>>> but it was edited by sehe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [qi::as_string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/as.html):

Output of demo program:

```
DEBUG: 'some\\"quoted\\"string.'
parse success
```

To be honest, it looks like you are really trying to parse 'verbatim' strings with possible escape chars. In the respect, the use of `lexeme` seem wrong (the spaces get eaten). If you want to see samples of escaped string parsing, see e.g._

- [Boost Spirit Implement small one-line DSL on a server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548592/boost-spirit-implement-small-one-line-dsl-on-a-server-application/14554966#14554966) (for this style)
- [Compiling a simple parser with Boost.Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404558/compiling-a-simple-parser-with-boost-spirit/9405546#9405546) (for escaping by duplication)
- [Parsing escaped strings with boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028169/parsing-escaped-strings-with-boost-spirit/4029386#4029386)
- [Parse quoted strings with boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289985/parse-quoted-strings-with-boostspirit/10294577#10294577)

### 2023 UPDATE

Revisited this answer because of a broken link to liveworkspace.org, and in 2023 I'd write this like so:

A simple rearrangement that I think could be made, at least might look like:

```
template <typename It> struct parser : qi::grammar<It> {
    parser() : parser::base_type(value) {
        phx::function some_func = [](auto const& s) { //
            std::cout << "DEBUG: " << s << "\n";
        };

        value = qi::raw['"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) >> '"'][some_func(qi::_1)];
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It> value;
};
```

> Note that we simply declare the rule without a skipper and drop the `lexeme` (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a8e000314a8595)

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

template <typename It> struct parser : qi::grammar<It> {
    parser() : parser::base_type(value) {
        phx::function some_func = [](auto const& s) { //
            std::cout << "DEBUG: " << s << "\n";
        };

        value = qi::raw['"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) >> '"'][some_func(qi::_1)];
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It> value;
};

bool doParse(std::string const& input) {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    try
    {
        parser<It> const p;

        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space);
        if (ok)
            std::cout << "parse success\n";
        else
            std::cerr << "parse failed: " << quoted(std::string(f, l), '\'') << "\n";

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: " << quoted(std::string(f,l), '\'') << "\n";
        return ok;
    } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e) {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cerr << e.what() << quoted(frag, '\'') << "\n";
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    return doParse(R"("some \"quoted\" string.")") ? 0 : 255;
}
```

Prints

```
DEBUG: "some \"quoted\" string."
parse success
```

Comment: +1 I was going to answer with `as_string` earlier, but could not for the life of me find it in the docs – 'parser directives', duh!

Comment: Added a concrete illustration of what would I think _needs_ to be fixed in the usage of `lexeme`.